# How to avoid code duplication in this helper method for a java class?

Tags: java

I have a java class like so (getters/setters through lombok):

```
public class Foo
{
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private byte[] byte1;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String byte1String;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String byte1Value;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  private byte[] byte2;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String byte2String;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String byte2Value;
}
```

And a following helper method to populate the values of a `Foo` object:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_BYTE_VALUE = "someDefaultValue";

private Foo getWithBytesAndValues(Foo foo)
{
    if (foo.getByte1String() != null)
    {
        foo.setByte1(new Base64(foo.getByte1String()).decode());
        if (foo.getByte1Value() == null)
        {
            foo.setByte1Value(DEFAULT_BYTE_VALUE);
        }
    }
    if (foo.getByte2String() != null)
    {
        foo.setByte2(new Base64(foo.getByte2String()).decode());
        if (foo.getByte2Value() == null)
        {
            foo.setByte2Value(DEFAULT_BYTE_VALUE);
        }
    }
    return foo;
}
```

My helper method looks like of messy.. and it seems I'm duplicating the same code twice. Is there any way to simplify the method?

Comment: Will those fields always contain those values (the ones you set on the helper method)?

Comment: @LppEdd when the method is called, `byte1String` or `byte2String` may be present in the `foo` object passed in the parameter. Similarly, `byte1Value` and `byte2Value` may be provided. Everything else should get populated based on the logic. So if `byte1String` is not null, set `byte1`. If `byte1Value` is not provided, then set the default value

Comment: Create a class containing the three fields (byte, byteString, byteValue). Replace the 6 fields in Foo by two instances of this new class. Call the same method on the two instances. It looks weird to return the Foo passed as argument: that sends the message that a new Foo is created by the method, but that's not the case. The method should return void.

Comment: @JBNizet that won't work because I need to maintain the variable names. I don't want to combine `byte1` and `byte2` into `byte` etc

Comment: @RonApple1996 what do you think of the solution proposed in my answer? Doesn't seem really that bad after all. Maybe not really memory efficient (still method references are better than lambda).

Comment: @RonApple1996 ping for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone forgive me for this. JB Nizet advice is **a lot** better, but I wanted to see what I could do.

```
public static void touch(
        final Consumer<byte[]> setByte,
        final Consumer<? super String> setByteValue,
        final Supplier<String> byteString,
        final Supplier<String> byteValue) {
    if (byteString != null) {
        setByte.accept(Base64.getDecoder().decode(byteString.get()));
    }

    if (byteValue.get() == null) {
        setByteValue.accept(DEFAULT_BYTE_VALUE);
    }
}
```

---

```
touch(
        foo::setByte1,
        foo::setByte1Value,
        foo::getByte1String,
        foo::getByte1Value
);

touch(
        foo::setByte2,
        foo::setByte2Value,
        foo::getByte2String,
        foo::getByte2Value
);
```

Comment: You can use `Supplier`s for the last two parameters so they don't get invoked until needed.

Comment: @daniu looks pretty neat!

Answer (score 0):

In the class Foo you can put the @Getter and @Setter annotations on the class to avoid duplication (pay attention that if you add another private attributes on this class that cant be public, you should remove the @Getter annotation to dont expose the private attribute):

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo
```

About the method getWithBytesAndValues, I suggest you put this method inside the class Foo because this methods makes get on Foo attrs and set another Foo attrs (the business rule is from domain Foo - see Domain Driven Design). You also can separate the inside logic in two methods:

```
public class Foo {

...

    public void setBytes()
        setByte1();
        setByte2();
    }

    private void setByte2() {
        if (getByte2String() != null) {
            setByte2(new Base64(getByte2String()).decode());
            if (getByte2Value() == null) {
                setByte2Value(DEFAULT_BYTE_VALUE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setByte1() {
        if (getByte1String() != null) {
            setByte1(new Base64(getByte1String()).decode());
            if (getByte1Value() == null) {
                setByte1Value(DEFAULT_BYTE_VALUE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```